# How to publish SQLite database when I publish my app to a device

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an application that uses a SQLite database. How do I publish the database when I create .apk file? Should I put it on some server?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9109728/265167

Answer (score 1):

You can create a exported flat file, ship it as a raw file in your apk package. And then run a import on first time load.

Edited
http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

Comment: is there any tutorial tells how to do that in steps ?

thanks :)

Comment: I have added a tutorial, this will help